# Swift UIButton text does not change

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have one UIButton in a UIView and I change its title. However, when I get the button title it is giving me the old title and not the changed one. However, when I call it from somewhere when the method is finished it's true

Thanks,

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, copy and paste the code

Comment: Please don't include the answer in your question. If an answer solved your issue, mark the answer as accepted; you can also post your own answer if you resolved your problem yourself or if you found a new solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping your if statements in a `performWithoutAnimation` block will prevent any delays in updates to the `titleLabel`.

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    if btnOne.titleLabel?.text == "qq" {
        btnOne.setTitle("metin", forState: .Normal)
        var a = btnOne.titleLabel?.text // "metin"
        mergeString += sender.titleLabel!.text!
    }
    ...
}
```